# Julia : update mutable struct by matching it's name to value of DataFrame column

Tags: julia

I would like to use a macro to mutate one of a set of mutable structs, based on the value of an id column in a DataFrame, where the id column matches the name of the structs.
I have a function that returns a dataframe created from a MySQL table :

```
function groups()
    log = DBInterface.execute(con, "SELECT * FROM pgdb1.groups")
    df  = DataFrame(log)
    return df
end
```

This is the dataframe, which has 2 columns, *id* and *pop* :

```
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ id       pop     
     │ String   String
─────┼───────────────────
   1 │ yg_1     6
   2 │ jyg_1    4
```

I have 2 structs, which match those ids, and i would like to update them based on rows of the dataframe :

```
mutable struct jyg_1
    pop::Int
end

mutable struct yg_1
    pop::Int
end
```

I have a macro that takes the dataframe. Based on the id of that row, i would like for it to update the struct that shares the same name as the row's id. Below is some pseudocode to give a sense of what  i was thinking but theres probably a much better way to do it.

```
macro filter()
    for row ∈ eachrow(groups())      
#       if row.id == [ some element in a list of stringified structs ]
#       update the jyg_1 or yg_1 struct with group.pop
#   DBInterface.execute(con, "INSERT INTO pgdb1.groups (pop) VALUES ('$pop' );")
#       end
    end
end
```

I'm not sure if someone could give me a push in the right direction. Thanks for considering this question!

Comment: I don't see why you need a macro for this. You can get the name of an object's struct as `string(typeof(obj))`. After comparing this name with the dataframe's `id` field you can set the value using normal syntax `obj.pop = new_value`.

Comment: how would u do that comparison?

Comment: If you want to update the structures, I assume you have instances of these structs in some collection. Is it correct? If so, you can iterate over that collection and apply `string(typeof(obj)) == row.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need convert the class name to `Symbol` and than `eval` it and thus obtain object. I believe you do not need a macro for that.

For an example consider `df`:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(id=["yg_1", "jyg_1"], pop=[4,6])
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ id      pop
     │ String  Int64
─────┼───────────────
   1 │ yg_1        4
   2 │ jyg_1       6
```

You can do:

```
julia> map.(eval.(Symbol.(df.id)), df.pop)
2-element Vector{Any}:
 yg_1(4)
 jyg_1(6)
```

Which is probably what you wanted.